# post object to spring mvc, all fields are null

Tags: javascript, spring, validation, post, model-view-controller

i would like to pass a object and validate it.
JavaScript:

```
var pic = {
         "picture":file,
         "ext":"png"
  }

fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: pic
    }).then(response => {
        if(response.status === 201){
            console.log('saved!!!');
            getPicture('no-cache');
        }
    })
```

My Controller is looking like that:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/user-pic")
    public ResponseEntity<String> submit(@Valid @ModelAttribute("pic") PictureDTO pictureDTO,
                                         BindingResult result, Model model,
                                         @AuthenticationPrincipal UserDetails userPrincipal) throws IOException {
...
}
```

My dto object is:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
public class PictureDTO {
    MultipartFile formDataWithFile;
    String pictureExtension;
}
```

And my validator

```
public class PictureValidator implements Validator {

...
        @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        try {
            //boths fields of this object are null
            //but validator will be triggered
            final PictureDTO pictureDTO = (PictureDTO) target;
     }
}
```

How can i fix it, to pass object from java-script to validator and my Fileds: MultipartFile and String will not be null anymore?

Comment: You can't pass an object to fetch body. It needs to be serialized and set appropriate content type header

Comment: i've fixed this. Just you "new FormData" on java-script side and append all fields to it. Then you can set formData to the body of fetch-request